# Is there a way to perform validation on related Orderable in InlinePanel in WagtailCMS?

Tags: python, django, validation, wagtail

I am using Wagtail CMS and I need some validation for my `Orderable` model. Like, ensuring that at most one of the fields is filled.

Normally, I would override the `clean(self)` method for the Django model, but calling `super().clean()` inside that method returns `None`. I am still able to access the fields with `self.field_name` and raising `ValidationError` still prevents the model from creation, but it doesn't show which fields caused the error for the model in the admin interface.

I have tried overriding the `clean` method, that stops the model from being committed but doesn't show errors on the interface

I have tried following [this part of the guide](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#customising-generated-forms), but the `clean` method there isn't even called for the `Orderable`.

This is the example of my `clean` method

```py
def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    has_image =  self.image is not None
    has_video = self.video_url is not None

    if has_image == has_video:
        raise ValidationError('Either a video or an image must be set')
```

I expect validation errors to show up in the admin interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dug into the wagtail source code and I think I found the way of how to access the form controls for the orderable.

Let's say you have a model for a page,

```
class TestPage(Page):

    testPageTitle = RichTextField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('testPageTitle'),
    InlinePanel('test_page_field')
    ]

    base_form_class = TestPageForm
```

with some orderable model, that is linked to the page through a related name 'test_page_field',

```
class TestPageField(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(TestPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='test_page_field')

    testPageFieldTitle = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
    FieldPanel('testPageFieldFieldTitle')
    ]
```

then you can access that within the clean method of the page, via `self.formsets['test_page_field'].forms`, which is a list of Django form objects, where the regular checks can be done and `.add_error()` method can be used. The relevant `base_form_class` would look as follows:

```
class TestPageForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):

    def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    #loop over linked orderables
    for form in self.formsets['test_page_field'].forms:

        #check first if form is valid, otherwise cleaned_data will not be accesible/set
        if form.is_valid():
            cleaned_form_data = form.clean()
            testPageFieldFieldTitle = cleaned_form_data.get('testPageFieldFieldTitle')

            #execute some validation condition, and raise the error if it fails
            if testPageFieldFieldTitle is None:
                form.add_error('testPageFieldFieldTitle', 'please dont leave me empty')

    return cleaned_data
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about 5 years old now and I recently ran into this issue. I thought I would add the official solution here with some extra information for people to learn about Orderables

**Note: This is updated as of Wagtail 6.0 and Django 5.0.**

Skip the bottom of this post for the full code solution.

Basically, you would `clean()` the Orderable object like you normally would a Django model. Behind the scenes an Orderable is a very vanilla Django model that looks like this:

```py
class Orderable(models.Model):
    sort_order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    sort_order_field = "sort_order"

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ["sort_order"]
```

Because an Orderable is just a standard Django model, you can `clean()` (and do other Django-y things) to it.

I've added additional `ValidationError`'s to the `clean()` method so that both fields get the validation error, and the content editors are more likely to see it as they scroll through the page they are working on.

```py
from django.db import models 
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from wagtail.models import Orderable, Page
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel, InlinePanel


class YourOrderableHere(Orderable):
    parental_key = ParentalKey("yourapp.CustomWagtailPage", related_name="custom_orderables")

    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='+',
    )
    video = models.ForeignKey(
        'yourapp.VideoModel',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='+',
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("image"),
        FieldPanel("video"),
    ]

    def clean(self) -> None:
        if self.image and self.video
            raise ValidationError({
                'image': ValidationError("You cannot have an image and a video set at the same time"),
                'video': ValidationError("You cannot have an image and a video set at the same time"),
            })
        return super().clean()


class CustomWagtailPage(Page):
    template = ".."
    parent_page_types = []
    subpage_types = []

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel("custom_orderables", label="Add Custom Orderable Item"),
    ]
```

Also note if you need to validate against any data in the `CustomWagtailPage` from within the Orderable, you can access that via `self.parental_key` (it will return the entire specific page instance).